# Access denied error while executing tensorflow example - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, data-pipeline

The link shows an example of data pipeline for images it works fine when I run directly on colab but when I use it on my laptop its gives this error. I've been using Keras for quite a while but this is the 1st time trying data pipelining and I couldn't find any answer for it.

This error occurs only when I run these 4 lines :-

```
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
timeit(train_ds)
uncached_ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds, cache=False)
timeit(uncached_ds)
filecache_ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds, cache="./flowers.tfcache")
timeit(filecache_ds)
```

> UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\Deep
>   Learning\Datasets\12 class dataset\motorbike : Access is denied. ;
>   Input/output error     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad I used os and glob library to denote location and access the directory while executing the code in my laptop which produced this error but after using 'pathlib' itself, it works like a charm...